# How to selectall checboxes in primefaces selectManyCheckbox

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to write a code where on selection of one checkbox all other checkboxes grouped under selectManycheckbox  are also selected.

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="inputSelectManyCheckbox" value="#{valueList}"  
valueChangeListener="#{valueChangeMethod}" label="#{label}">
              <p:ajax listener="#{actionListener}" />
 </p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [check f:items value based on p:selectManyCheckbox using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970385/check-fitems-value-based-on-pselectmanycheckbox-using-javascript)

Comment: Thanks Hatem, that means only way to do it is via javascript?

Comment: You can do it in the backend, but for me it's not meant to be in the backend, it's more likely a client-side function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{...}">
  <p:ajax event="change" 
          listener="yourBean.checkAll()" 
          update="inputSelectManyCheckbox" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

... and ...

```
@ManagedBean
@....Scoped
public class YourBean {
  public void checkAll(){
    for(Boolean b : this.getValueList()){
      b = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Please note: the value of a `p:selectManyCheckbox` is a list of only the selected items! I hope you can adapt my example to your code!